# Remover None de uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Se eu tenho uma lista:

```
lista = [None, 'Hotjar']
```

Como faço para remover o `None` e o print da lista me trazer apenas os valores?

```
lista = ['Hotjar']
```

Comment: Simplifiquei a sua pergunta removendo todo o código que não condiz com a pergunta. Poderia confirmar se não alterou o sentido? Podemos reverter se de fato alterou.

Comment: A pergunta continua com o mesmo sentido, porém, acho importante manter a parte do print.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando-se que você não precisa manter o mesmo objeto de lista, basta criar uma nova lista sem os `None`s.

Do jeito direto:

```
entrada = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, 5, 6, None, 7, 8, 9]
saida = []
for item in entrada:
    if item is not None:
        saida.append(item)
```

Usando *list comprehension*:

```
entrada = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, 5, 6, None, 7, 8, 9]
saida = [x for x in entrada if x is not None]
```